# Android Studio running webservice on an emulator

Tags: android, web-services, webserver

I want to sync my android data with SQL Server Data.

I have followed the tutorial on http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/

The difference is I am using web service developed in Visual Studio instead of PHP. I want to get Data from database and sync with Android Device.

I am using Android Studio.

When I request the same on my Local PC using http://localhost:57059/api/mpapi/GetAllWriting it is working fine and giving me the output in XML format. whereas when I'm trying to run the same on Browser on My Android Emulator I'm getting Page Not found.

I am using URL http://10.0.2.2/api/mpapi/GetAllWriting

I even tried using http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/mpapi/GetAllWriting which is giving me request time out. Restarted the emulator but not working. Do I need to do any make changes? I checked other websites like yahoo.com and google.com on emulator those are working fine [Internet is working fine].

P.S.
The code in Android:

```
 client.post("http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/mpapi/GetAllWriting", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
```

Comment: did you do port redirection with your emulator ?

Comment: Yes. When I enter http://10.0.2.2 on my emulator it return the IIS page